# Ivy on hybrid apps(angular+angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, angular, ivy, angular-ivy

Very simple question, my team has upgrade from angular 7 to 11.
I would like to know, can we enable ivy(flag:true) when our app is a hybrid app(angularjs typescipt + angular), if so what are the changes which need to be made, if not possible then why?

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance!